# split batch by Javascript for JSON string- Mirth Connect

Tags: javascript, json, mirth

The below message I 'm trying to process through a channel and I need to split this message into individual objects and pass through the destination.
I found a related post: https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/15485-split-batch-by-javascript-for-json-string?view=thread
But here splitter at the object level and mine one includes two levels[relatedPost][1]
I tried different ways by changing the above-posted code it doesn't work for me, please help me with it if anyone can.

```js
{
    encounterList[
        [{
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "71010",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160417",
                    "unitAmount": "166.00",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "166.00",
                    "chargeCode": "4401010",
                    "deptCode": "4040",
                    "modifier1": "TC",
                    "revenueCode": "0324",
                    "providerId": "92038"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "73110",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "199.00",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "199.00",
                    "chargeCode": "4409360",
                    "deptCode": "4040",
                    "modifier1": "TC",
                    "revenueCode": "0320",
                    "providerId": "92038"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "84443",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "148.25",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "148.25",
                    "chargeCode": "4110886",
                    "deptCode": "4011",
                    "revenueCode": "0301",
                    "providerId": "00701"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "84443",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "69.50",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "69.50",
                    "chargeCode": "4171812",
                    "deptCode": "4011",
                    "revenueCode": "0301",
                    "providerId": "95544"
                }
            }
        ], [{
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "71010",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160417",
                    "unitAmount": "166.00",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "166.00",
                    "chargeCode": "4401010",
                    "deptCode": "4040",
                    "modifier1": "TC",
                    "revenueCode": "0324",
                    "providerId": "92038"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "73110",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "199.00",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "199.00",
                    "chargeCode": "4409360",
                    "deptCode": "4040",
                    "modifier1": "TC",
                    "revenueCode": "0320",
                    "providerId": "92038"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "84443",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "148.25",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "148.25",
                    "chargeCode": "4110886",
                    "deptCode": "4011",
                    "revenueCode": "0301",
                    "providerId": "00701"
                }
            }, {
                "codeList": {
                    "type": "Secondary",
                    "statusCode": "Original",
                    "ordinality": "9999",
                    "code": "84443",
                    "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
                    "unitAmount": "69.50",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "extendedAmount": "69.50",
                    "chargeCode": "4171812",
                    "deptCode": "4011",
                    "revenueCode": "0301",
                    "providerId": "95544"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    }
```

```
The output I want is an individual object like:
```

```js
  {
        "codeList": {
            "type": "Secondary",
            "statusCode": "Original",
            "ordinality": "9999",
            "code": "71010",
            "procedureDateTime": "20160417",
            "unitAmount": "166.00",
            "quantity": "1",
            "extendedAmount": "166.00",
            "chargeCode": "4401010",
            "deptCode": "4040",
            "modifier1": "TC",
            "revenueCode": "0324",
            "providerId": "92038"
        }
    }
```

```
Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: That json object looks wonky. Is that actually what it looks like?

Comment: @Kinglish - I was about to say the same. It is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The json object looks off, so I took a stab at what I thought it might actually be. Here's how to iterate through the following json, and you can apply your logic for each block inside the `forEach` loop.

```js
let json = {
  encounterList: [{
    "codeList": {
      "type": "Secondary",
      "statusCode": "Original",
      "ordinality": "9999",
      "code": "71010",
      "procedureDateTime": "20160417",
      "unitAmount": "166.00",
      "quantity": "1",
      "extendedAmount": "166.00",
      "chargeCode": "4401010",
      "deptCode": "4040",
      "modifier1": "TC",
      "revenueCode": "0324",
      "providerId": "92038"
    }
  }, {
    "codeList": {
      "type": "Secondary",
      "statusCode": "Original",
      "ordinality": "9999",
      "code": "73110",
      "procedureDateTime": "20160416",
      "unitAmount": "199.00",
      "quantity": "1",
      "extendedAmount": "199.00",
      "chargeCode": "4409360",
      "deptCode": "4040",
      "modifier1": "TC",
      "revenueCode": "0320",
      "providerId": "92038"
    }
  }]
};

json.encounterList.forEach(block => {
  console.log('block:', block);
  // your logic here...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab, too. I think it's probably something like this or else it isn't actually different from the reference post.

```json
{
   "encounterList":[
      [
         {
            "codeList":{
               "type":"Secondary",
               "statusCode":"Original",
               "ordinality":"9999",
               "code":"71010",
               "procedureDateTime":"20160417",
               "unitAmount":"166.00",
               "quantity":"1",
               "extendedAmount":"166.00",
               "chargeCode":"4401010",
               "deptCode":"4040",
               "modifier1":"TC",
               "revenueCode":"0324",
               "providerId":"92038"
            }
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "codeList":{
               "type":"Secondary",
               "statusCode":"Original",
               "ordinality":"9999",
               "code":"71010",
               "procedureDateTime":"20160417",
               "unitAmount":"166.00",
               "quantity":"1",
               "extendedAmount":"166.00",
               "chargeCode":"4401010",
               "deptCode":"4040",
               "modifier1":"TC",
               "revenueCode":"0324",
               "providerId":"92038"
            }
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Since we're talking about mirth, which uses Rhino for the javascript engine, it doesn't yet implement `Array.prototype.flatMap` or you could use that. Instead you'll probably want something like this (modifying the code from the reference post.)

```js
if (!queue) {
    queue = new java.util.LinkedList();
    var obj = JSON.parse(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(reader));
    obj.encounterList.forEach(subList => {
        subList.forEach(encounter => {
            queue.add(JSON.stringify(encounter));
        });
    });
    $gc('queue', queue);
}
```